# Scrollbars on overflow div do not appear when content is added to div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, overflow

I have an HTML Document that looks a bit like this, only is far more complex and harder to control:

```
<body>
  <div id="title">This div does not do anything, just stays at the top.</div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="navigation">Some navigation</div>
    <div id="content">Most of the content</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Then I have a stylesheet that includes the following:

```
#container
{  
   height: auto !important;
   overflow: visible !important;
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   position: relative;
   width: auto !important;
}
```

This all works absolutely perfectly. The `title` section stays at the top of the page, the `container` div becomes scrollable if the content is long enough to need to scroll, otherwise it doesn't.

The problem is, that I am then using Javascript to add a whole lot more stuff to the `content` div. This means that the `content` div is getting longer than the page *after* it has loaded and this seems to mean, in IE8 at least, that the scrollbars on the `container` never get activated, so once the Javascript added content falls off the bottom of the page it becomes inaccessible.

It doesn't help that the minute I start tinkering with the IE developer tools, the scrollbars vanish altogether and I can't make them reappear, so it becomes somewhat hard to test.

Comment: Perhaps you can use some of this http://remysharp.com/2008/01/21/fixing-ie-overflow-problem/

Comment: @mplungjan - thanks for the comment, but I think that is solving a different problem.

Comment: `!important` is a nasty hack for when you don't understand CSS specificity! Don't ever use it unless you absolutely need to. Using it  means the values can't be overridden anywhere else in the code, that is you lose the cascading aspect of CSS. You may think you don't need to right now since you really want your DIV one way, but I've often needed it in future and had to track `!important`.

Comment: @JuanMendes The HTML and CSS I was working with here was not written by me. In fact I believe I was working with SharePoint 2010's built in styles, so I guess it's Microsoft's engineers who don't understand CSS specificity. That should be a surprise to nobody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that has worked was a simple hackaround of resizing the element with JavaScript to match the size it actually is once I have added the extra data to it, like this:

```
document.all['container'].style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight+"px";
```

Of course, this doesn't entirely circumvent the problem- for that we need a new function:

```
function resizeResults()
{
    var resultPanel=document.all["container"];
    var topPanel=document.all["title"];
    var newHeight= document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    newHeight -= topPanel.clientHeight;
    resultPanel.style.height=newHeight;
}
```

Then we can use `window.attachEvent("onresize", resizeResults);` to ensure that we don't lose the scrollbar or have it otherwise messed around when the user changes the window size.

Comment: `document.all`? Really? Have you been reading books from the 90s?

Comment: The problem is that your DIV is set auto height. That means **grow with the content**! You expect it to take the initial size and then not be auto anymore??? You have to do it with JS as you figured out, but your answer doesn't seem like you understand the real problem.

Comment: @juanmendes That is possible, I don't recall whether I tried changing that, but I tried everything at some point. As for `document.all` - some of us have to work with clients whose browsers go back to... well, to IE6 at any rate.

Comment: there's no excuse to use `document.all` with IE6, or IE5 for that matter. If you need to support IE4, look for a new job!

Comment: Is there really not? I don't recall getElementById being cross platform until relatively recently.

Comment: It's available in every browser since IE 5.5 and Netscape 6, both released around 2000

Comment: Well, there's a habit I got into early on and just never got back out of :D

Answer (score 1):

I know IE8 has some issues with overflow-y.

You should try with this maybe.

```
-ms-overflow-y: scroll;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It didn't appear to help, but a very useful tip - not something I had heard of at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say if this will work without seeing more code, but why not remove the styles from your css and add them with javascript, once the content has loaded.

Comment: The main reason is that I am working with themable pages so I need the styles to be rendered from the theme's CSS file and I would prefer not to have to encode it all in JavaScript. Unfortunately the themable stuff I am working with is Sharepoint related as well so the code for the page as a whole is very complex and involved, which makes it hard to put together a basic example, though I am working on it.

Comment: @glenatron. Fair enough. Sounds like a fight!!  Could you do it for this one instance?  Or, if you prefer not, how about keeping the styles in the CSS and then assign that class to the `div` after the content has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the styles you have given for the element to make it scroll before loading ajax content to it.After loading ajax content then add those attributes again.